# Digitizing audio cassettes

Tags: software-rec, audio, recording, tape, cassette

I am looking for a freeware equivalent to Adobe Audition software i.e. a software for digitizing audio cassettes. Please suggest some.

Comment: related question: http://superuser.com/questions/44562/convert-a-cassette-tape-recording-to-digital-format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not really the software but the hardware. Assuming you solved this (Audio Out of the tape deck in the Line In port of a sound card?), [**Audacity**](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) is a great alternative to Adobe Audition.

[image]

Audacity is of course not restricted to digitizing audio cassettes.